# Cocos 2dx control playback speed of currently playing audio effect

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

Hi I am playing a sound effect in a cocos game using this method from `SimpleAudioEngine`
Is there a way to control the playback rate (speed up or slow down) of this audio at runtime.

```
int playEffect(const char* filePath, bool loop = false,
                                    float pitch = 1.0f, float pan = 0.0f, float gain = 1.0f);
```

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that, so I would recommend making the appropriate additional versions of the audio with speed changes.